# Iterate through an xml file for a selected node

Tags: asp.net, xml

i have an xml file called  image.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

 <Image>
     <Overview>0</Overview>
     <Gallery1>0</Gallery1>
     <Gallery2>0</Gallery2>
 </Image>
```

code

```
string strGallery  =textbox1.text;
  lets  say text box  contains value  = Gallery1
```

when an add  an image in the  gallery1  using an  file upload  control 
when i save the  image in the respective  folder like:  c:\demo\image..

now  i   should  read the above  xml  file   as  i have  added  an image in the   gallery1   folder  now  i   should  increment that value  by "1"  because i have  added  an image  to the gallery1  folder.

0 intaiilly which  was
 after adding the  image  now i  should  it  become 1
like this if  i have  added  an image in the gallery2  folder

then i  should  incremented    <`Gallery2>1</Gallery2>.`  so if  next time if i add  one more image in gallery2 then the  count should be  2

so how  can i loop  through the  elements   for the desired gallery
 becuase  if type in my textbox as gallery1  then gallery1 count should be incremetd
 if  type in my textbox  as gallery2  then gallery2  count   should be incremetd
  and then save  the  xml   file  once  modifcation is  done .

so  how can i achive this functionality
 thank you

so how can i achive this one

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood it correctly, but try something like this:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml("<Image>..."); // or xml.Load("yourfile.xml");

string name = "Gallery1";
XmlElement gallery = xml.SelectSingleNode("//" + name) as XmlElement;
if(gallery == null)
{
    gallery = xml.CreateElement(name);
    gallery.InnerText = "1";
    xml.DocumentElement.AppendChild(gallery);
}
 else
{
   gallery.InnerText = (Int32.Parse(gallery.InnerText) + 1).ToString();
}
```